# Quorum: permissioned-nodes.js and static-nodes.js

Tags: quorum, permissioned-chain

How do I proper use `permissioned-nodes.js`?

According to this information: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/Security

If the `--permissioned` flag is set, the node looks for a file named `<data-dir>/permissioned-nodes.json`. This file contains the whitelist of enodes that this node can connect to and accept connections from. BUT if I rename `static-nodes.js` into `permissioned-nodes.js` my nodes don't want to start.

1.) Do I have to use `permissioned-nodes.js` additionally to `static-nodes.js`?

2.) And what is the best way to quickly check whether the network is already permissioned or not?

Answer (score 1):

`permissioned-nodes.json` is the white-list of remote nodes that are allowed to connect.

`static-nodes.json` is the list of remote nodes to which to connect on startup and to which to reconnect on connection loss.

Hence, you'll need both files. IF you only have `permissioned-nodes.json` and no `static-nodes.json` your node will not connect to any other node on startup, except node discovery is on.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to quickly check whether the network is really permissioned? Even if I start with --permissioned and have the permissioned-nodes in the datadir folder, there was no info about the permissioned status of the network on startup

Comment: I guess there is no console command to check this later.